# How to prevent map failure when element is missing

Tags: angular

Is there a way to make a mapping more failure proof ? I implemented a mapping when data comes in via the following code.

```
getSurveyRequest(surveyId: string) {
        return this.api.get({endpoint: '/survey/request/' + surveyId})
            .pipe(
                map(res => res as IApiResponseBody<ISurvey[]>),
                map((res: IApiResponseBody) => { res.Data = SurveyRequestService.adaptMainSurveyList(res.Data);
                                                 console.log(res.Data);
                                                 if ( res.Success === true) {
                                                        return res.Data;
                                                    }
                                                 return null;
            })
            );
    }
```

and here is my static Adapter

```
static adaptMainSurveyList(surveylist): ISurvey {
        if (surveylist) {
            return {
                docId: surveylist.docId,
                firstName: surveylist.contact.fname,
                lastName: surveylist.contact.lname,
                email: surveylist.contact.email,
                phone: surveylist.contact.phone,
                address1: surveylist.property.address1,
                address2: surveylist.property.address2,
                city: surveylist.property.city,
                state: surveylist.property.state,
                zip: surveylist.property.zip,
                status: surveylist.property.status
            };
        }

    }
```

all works fine, but when for example there is no contact or property element in the Data element it fails completely, when there is empty contact and property elements it works again. So i am not sure why this is happening and what i can do to make the code more robust so in case the api returns some malformed data it doesn't cause to big of issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is a means of *safe tree traversal*, and unfortunately, Typescript does not support an out-of-the-box means of performing an easy and clean safe tree traversal.

Sure, you can do logical checks with what amounts to several inline ternary statements. See below for an example,

```js
static adaptMainSurveyList(surveylist): ISurvey {
  if (surveylist) {
    return {
      docId:     surveylist.docId,
      firstName: surveylist.contact  ? surveylist.contact.fname     : null,
      lastName:  surveylist.contact  ? surveylist.contact.lname     : null,
      email:     surveylist.contact  ? surveylist.contact.email     : null,
      phone:     surveylist.contact  ? surveylist.contact.phone     : null,
      address1:  surveylist.property ? surveylist.property.address1 : null,
      address2:  surveylist.property ? surveylist.property.address2 : null,
      city:      surveylist.property ? surveylist.property.city     : null,
      state:     surveylist.property ? surveylist.property.state    : null,
      zip:       surveylist.property ? surveylist.property.zip      : null,
      status:    surveylist.property ? surveylist.property.status   : null
    };
  }
}
```

This is probably fine and probably the best you can get with your current data structure. Unfortunately, if you need to go more than one or two levels down, your ternary operators end up having several conditions and it just looks bad.

However, if you don't mind using a third-party library, lodash has a function that accomplishes safe tree traversal nicely, called [`_.get(object, path, [defaultValue])`](https://lodash.com/docs/#get).

> Gets the value at path of object. If the resolved value is undefined, the defaultValue is returned in its place.
>
> Since
>   3.7.0
>
> Arguments
>
> - object (Object): The object to query.
> - path (Array|string): The path of the property to get.
> - [defaultValue] (*): The value returned for undefined resolved values.
>
> Returns
>   (*): Returns the resolved value.

Using lodash, you could modify your constructor as below:

```js
static adaptMainSurveyList(surveylist): ISurvey {
        if (surveylist) {
            return {
                docId:     _.get(surveylist, "docId", null),
                firstName: _.get(surveylist, "contact.fname", null),
                lastName:  _.get(surveylist, "contact.lname", null),
                email:     _.get(surveylist, "contact.email", null),
                phone:     _.get(surveylist, "contact.phone", null),
                address1:  _.get(surveylist, "property.address1", null),
                address2:  _.get(surveylist, "property.address2", null),
                city:      _.get(surveylist, "property.city", null),
                state:     _.get(surveylist, "property.state", null),
                zip:       _.get(surveylist, "property.zip", null),
                status:    _.get(surveylist, "status", null)
            };
        }
    }
```

As a side note, you can actually do this in your templates in Angular with interpolation. The [Elvis operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator) in your Angular templates `{{a?.b?.c?.d}}` is a valid means of safe tree traversal for your template, but it doesn't work in Typescript.

Comment: looks like a clean solution. One thing, your code is off as you dont need to specify surveylist in path. Thats the name of the object so to get to docId your path is only docId not surveylist.docID

Answer (score 0):

Check all the attributes of the response

```
static adaptMainSurveyList(surveylist): ISurvey {
        if (surveylist) {
            return {
                docId: surveylist.docId ,
                ... (surveylist.contact && firstName: surveylist.contact.fname) ,
                ... (surveylist.contact && lastName: surveylist.contact.lname) ,
                ... (surveylist.contact && email: surveylist.contact.email),
                ... (surveylist.contact && phone: surveylist.contact.phone),
                ... (surveylist.property && address1: surveylist.property.address1) ,
                // likewise for the rest
            };
        }

    }
```

This will prevent to read property on undefined. As now the data is filled only with values that are present in the server response. This will mean that when you will use the output of `adaptMainSurveyList`, you'll need to check if a certain property is present before using it.

If you'd rather set a default null value to value that are not in the response data, here is the way to go.

```
static adaptMainSurveyList(surveylist): ISurvey {
            if (surveylist) {
                return {
                    docId: surveylist.docId || null,
                    firstName: (surveylist.contact && surveylist.contact.fname) || null ,
                    lastName: (surveylist.contact && surveylist.contact.lname) || null,
                    email: (surveylist.contact && surveylist.contact.email) || null,
                    phone: (surveylist.contact && surveylist.contact.phone) || null,
                    address1: (surveylist.property && surveylist.property.address1) || null ,
                    // likewise for the rest
                };
            }

        }
```

Comment: Is there any requirements for this to work ? in my case i get a bunch of errors when i use that code. It complains that it can not find firstName, lastName etc as well as An object literal cannot have multiple properties with the same name in strict mode.

Comment: You will need to check the attributes when you will use the output of the method `adaptMainSurveyList`. For the error you "An object literal cannot have multiple properties with the same name in strict mode" are you sure you copied exactly the code of the answer ? Because the same property is not used twice. See my edit answer if you'd rather want to set a default null value